# sentence explanation

Tags: phrase-choice

The constitutional guarantee for free Speech may have been targeted at protecting native Speakers of English from censorship,but it is not a great _____to interpret it as protecting the right to express oneself in any natural language or dialect.

A enigma
B **extension**
C sacrifice
D condemnation
E attenuation

the correct answer is (B), any explanation for that, please?

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions for all candidate words? What did they tell you, and why are you still confused? For what it's worth, I'd say that idiomatically, most native speakers would probably say *...but it's **no great stretch** [to assume a more extended interpretation]*, so my guess is whoever set the test wasn't a native speaker anyway.

Comment: yup, I've searched for all these words, but I don't understand the sentence itself! why it's not ANY OTHER OPTION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is contrasting free speech for English versus free speech for all languages. So ...

A. An "enigma" is a puzzle, a mystery. Would it be a mystery for free speech to apply to all languages? Not really.

B. An "extension" is something added on, what you get when you make something bigger. Free speech in all languages is bigger than free speech in one language. This makes sense.

C. A "sacrifice" is when you give something up. What would you be giving up by applying free speech to many languages? This doesn't seem to make sense.

D. "Condemnation" is when you criticize something. What would be criticized by expanding free speech? Nothing. (The content of the free speech might be criticizing something, but here we're not talking about the content, but about the existence.)

E. "Attenuation" is when something thins out or evaporates. That is, attenuation makes something smaller. Here we're talking about making something bigger, so it's the opposite. No.

So the only one that makes sense is B.